# Package that is linked with npm link doesn't update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have two modules - my main project and a component library - where I want to link the lib to the main project. Both is working with webpack and react. So I did:

In comp-lib dir:

> npm link

In project dir:

> npm link comp-lib

The package is showing up in the node_modules folder, but when I work on the component library the changes are not reflected in main project. What am I missing out?

I couldn't really find something about this issue on Google and the npm link doc just says about the example: "Now, any changes to ~/projects/node-redis will be reflected in ~/projects/node-bloggy/node_modules/node-redis/."

Comment: `npm link` will create a symbolic link so it's basically the same folder. Did you make sure to rebuild your comp-lib after modifying it as the file specified in the `main` field of the package.json will be used?

Comment: Yes, I rebuild it, output is: bundle.js in root dir. Entrypoint in package.json is bundle.js. But also the whole folder structure should be updated then, right? If I add a component in components folder I can't see it.

Comment: Yeah it should, I don't know if it works the same on Windows but the first command create a symlink from your comp-lib folder to your global npm folder (`/usr/local/lib/node_modules` for example) and the second one from this previous global folder to `project-dir/node_modules/comp-lib`. Maybe you can check if the links are valid and point to the right folders.

Comment: I just figured out that when I manually synchronize comp-lib folder in main project it shows the changes. IntelliJ offers this option in context menu on right click. Not sure if this is supposed to work this way but at least it works.

Answer (score 33):

Had similar problem with linked package - `npm link dep` was picking up old version of "dep".

Running `npm link` (again) in "dep" folder solved the problem. Theoretically it should be called only once, but for some reason it gets out of sync sometimes.

Thus in order to reliably update linked project, execute these steps after each change:

1. Rebuild linked project
2. run `npm link`
3. In host project run `npm link dep`

Comment: Node you could also do `npm link ../path/to/dep` from the consuming package rather than doing it in two steps

Answer (score 7):

I don't remember exactly what problems I had and I am also not sure if all of that is necessary but for me it works great.

I added the following mini script to the package.json scripts list

```
"scripts": {
  "clean": "if exist dist ( rd /S /Q dist)",
  "updateLink": "npm run clean && tsc && npm rm my-lib -g && npm link"
}
```

(Replace "my-lib" with your package name)

Then simply call `npm run updateLink` whenever you change something in the lib.

What it does:

- **npm run clean** deletes the dist folder. Useful if you have renamed files and the typecript compiler does not delete the old files but builds new ones in parallel
- **tsc** to compile ts->js to the dist folder
- **npm rm my-lib -g && npm link** to remove your lib and add it again from the global modules folder. I don't remember why I had to remove it first but it solved some problem I guess.

Comment: getting an error `sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `if exist dist ( rd /S /Q dist)'`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the Node versions of the main project and dependency project match precisely.

If you use `nvm` to manage multiple projects on multiple node versions, the `npm link` will produce the symbolic link only in the node version that `npm link` was initiated from (i.e., the dependency project).

Answer (score 4):

2023, and npm still seems to have quite a few problems with `npm link`, it's a popular frustration in their github issues. If none of the other answers work for you, the following seem to fix things for us:

**Option 1: Give Your Local Package a Unique Version Number**

1. In the local package you're working on (OP called this their component library) set `version` in package.json to something totally unique, something that hasn't ever been published before. Let's say you make that `1.1.99`
2. Build the package, then run `npm link`
3. In the project you want to use the package, run `npm link mypackage@1.1.99`

One source of this problem seems to be npm getting confused with what you are trying to `npm link` to. Since you've never published 1.1.99 to the cloud or even locally, npm can't really confuse `mypackage@1.1.99` with anything other than the local version of the package you just created. Annoyingly, you'll of course need to remember to revert the version number change in package.json

**Option 2: Delete the `nodule_modules` cache**

Option 1 has worked reliably for us; something a little quicker that seems to usually work; run this in your project (not in the package, but in the project that uses the package):

`rm -rf node_modules/.cache/ && npm link mypackage`

npm caching some old reference to mypackage sometimes being the source of the problem, this seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you bumped version on your component, and forgot to increase the version on your main project.
Then, any `npm` operation will download the version indicated in the `package-lock.json`: the outdated version, thus removing the link set up by `npm link`.

Comment: Thank you for commenting about package versions. My problem ended up being that I hadn't incremented my package version in my library project. I wasted far too much time trying to figure out what was happening, but your comment finally put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that my module/package in this case was exporting the build files. I didnt fix it because we export multiple files from multiple components but if you run into this issue, change `main` (and `exports` in my case) to whatever file exports your modules

```html
  "main": "./dist/shared-lib.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/shared-lib.es.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/shared-lib.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/shared-lib.umd.js"
    },
    "./style": "./dist/style.css"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually want my `npm link ../other-package-in-monorepo` saved in the **package.json** and I remember that NPM did it *sometimes* for me, but other times you can only find changes in `node_modules`, so the only reliable way I could find to ensure *package.json* changes is to edit it manually using this syntax:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "your-package-name": "file:../other-package-in-monorepo"
  },
```